# Why do web applications send HTML over the wire?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

This question pertains to web applications. I have very little web app development experience, so might be missing some very obvious points/issues. Please point them out.

As I understand, in most web applications, a web server sends HTML over the wire to a client (browser). This happens every time a HTTP request is made. I feel this is very wasteful of bandwidth.

1) Since browsers can run JavaScript, why don't we just send a JavaScript program which can generate the webpage's HTML content (which the browser then renders).

2) Further a browser might cache the JavaScript program and next time the server only need send the data. The protocol might involve the browser sending the "program version" it has.

Consider an example of a relatively simple website Hacker News [http://news.ycombinator.com]. Let us separate the data (30 posts + their metadata) from its presentation. Assuming 1) above, the server can just send the data (say in JSON) + a JavaScript program to generate HTML. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/782329) shows the idea. The data for the 30 posts is in JSON [http://www.json.org/js.html] format. For this particular example the data transferred is cut in 1/2 (size of data+JavaScript / size of HTML). Further if browsers can do 2) above, it reduces the data transferred on each visit to 1/4 (size of data / size of HTML). [Note: this analysis is without considering compression; gzip,deflate is very successful in reducing the size of HTML. But isn't prevention better than cure?]

I see atleast the following advantages of this :-
* For most web pages, it will reduce the size of data transferred over the wire.
* Forces web apps to separate data from its presentation.

Disadvantages might include - more complex browsers, time to run the JavaScript program to generate HTML (this might get offset by the reduction in data size).

Now my question is - why are web applications not developed this way, or, why do web applications send HTML over the wire? Surely the web server (sending out HTML) doesn't care about HTML at all, so why should it, first, generate it, and then send it over the wire?

Comment: Wouldn't the JS that generates the HTML be in fact larger than the HTML?

Comment: @tenor, atleast for the Hacker News example that isn't the case.

Comment: There are plenty of web applications that work that way.

Comment: @Pointy, can you please elaborate more on that

Comment: Applications like GMail more-or-less do exactly what you say. Often, a skeletal HTML file will come from the server, but thereafter updates are done with client-side code that interprets more "pure" data responses to async HTTP requests. Indeed, Stackoverflow itself does a lot of that.

Comment: Applications like Hacker News on the other hand should do as much on the server as possible because its target audience (programmers) tend to be one of the few groups of people that 1. knows that you can turn off javascript and sometimes do turn off javascript 2. knows that you can browse the web from a plain old (non smartphone) phone and sometimes does it. 3. know about text mode user agents like elinks and lynx and even wget and curl and do in fact use them from time to time. Generally speaking, programmers appreciate it if your site is plain-old HTML.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for mentioning that. At my workplace we are building a web app where the server just exposes a REST style web API ("pure" data responses).

Comment: @na_ka_ra well best of luck - it's certainly not a *bad* idea and in fact a lot of people strongly recommend it - see my answer for some more reasons why work is still done on the server

Comment: Search engines arent too happy about "program structures" either. I believe REST style gives almost the same problems as using Flash or Java or any other "scriptable" language. So if you dont have a static "h1" then your headline isnt found as easily from Google etc.

Comment: sounds like xml + xslt. useful sometimes, but down n dirty html is just so easy...even a caveman can do it.

Comment: This has been the trend in the last 6-7 years ---> exactly what OP has argued -- servers and API end points and the front end is a react / vue /angular app which handles the presentation of JSON data .... but I'm sure that back end developers will fight back so they can use their existing workflow and HTML templates and to render changes by sending html over the wire .... we're seeing that now with LiveView (phoenix) and solutions like tubo-rails  - which focus on updating the DOM but doing so with html, and not JSON.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few reasons, some of them historical this is by no means a complete list but just some of my experiences:

1. HTML predates JS, and a lot of scripts and libraries predate JS
2. Older browsers (think IE<=6) had rubbish, inconsistent JS engines, their rendering engines were much more consistent in how they treat HTML. So many more libraries and scripts predate *consistent* JS
3. It is a nightmare to debug applications written as you suggest if they are not constructed right (we have one at my work, it takes 30 minutes to find where a piece of html is actually generated)
4. It is a lot more work to do it right - why not use templates or static docs or something much simpler
5. Its not really a problem - HTML compresses really well
6. What you suggest *is* done - its called AJAX (OK, so ajax is more general than this but you all know what i mean)
7. It simply doesn't work for most plain-text user agents including those used by most search engines. If this page is serving most of your content, its generally a good idea to make it easy for Google to parse

Answer (score 5):

Well the obvious reason on **why** this is the case is that JavaScript wasn't around when we started sending HTML around, and HTML was an improvement to sending around plaintext documents.

The reason we don't do this now: we eschew complex solutions to problems that aren't really problems.

Average internet connections download nearly 1M bytes per second, and web browsers are quite adept at parsing and starting to render this HTML before it's even all ready to be. They're also great at parallelizing the downloading of resources on the page. If we want to save a few bytes at the cost of some compute cycles, we gzip content before sending it. Problem solved.

And for the record, we do this with AJAX in complex webpages (checkout Github's source browsing for a great example of how awesome this can be).

Comment: browsers might be happy, but I can't help but feel that the servers, connections are too pleased with this arrangement :). Isn't it the case that most bottlenecks in web applications are on the server side?

Comment: Sure, but it's not bandwidth-related. Usually after demand for cpu cycles increase to the point that scaling becomes necessary, the big bottleneck becomes database access. Concurrency, immediately-available data, and scalability are a lot more relevant problems. That's why there are N+1 new database systems coming out every day (CloudDB, Cassandra, etc., etc., etc.) :P

Answer (score 2):

What you suggest is basically what a [JavaScript full stack framework like ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com) does.  You can create rich, data intensive applications without writing any HTML -- well, only enough to reference the necessary .js libraries.  The complex DOM needed for layouts, grids, forms etc is all created by the framework.

Comment: Especially in mobile applications, it is becoming common to send just one html page and then send json over the wire and render client side.

Answer (score 2):

What you suggest can, and is, done.  Remember, web pages used to be static documents. Full blown web-based applications are a relatively recent idea.

I might also suggest that it isn't necessarily more efficient, especially when your pages are sent gzipped.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that HTML is older. Why is C99 not fully implemented with a lot of compilers? They figure 1989 is new enough for them. Also, JavaScript exercises a lot more control over people's browsers than they seem to want. Conditional statements and encoded data pose a security concern, and some people want to keep that can of worms closed to begin with. True, HTML is a very inefficient markup, but the size is insignificant compared to the images you download from the internet. That favicon takes up as much data as the page itself, and it's only 16 pixels across.

Comment: @Anonymous, you make a very valid point that the size might be insignificant, but as far as the favicons are concerned, aren't they cached? Why can't we cache all static data?

Comment: You can. Servers can send out a header that tells the client to cache anything from the web page itself to any images or really anything. The server is in complete control of the caching until you hit the refresh button, clear your cache, or exit your browser.

Comment: `16*16=256*(32/8)+BMP_HEADER_BYTES = 1KB + 52B` And this page is about 45KB, according to Chrome Developer tools. But yes, 400x100 images are a different story.

Comment: Yep. Well, Stack Overflow is kind of a larger website, what with all the menus and stuff, but yeah, the bigger images are what really get you.

Answer (score 1):

A good reason that the server-side code of a web application might do lots of HTML template work on the server side is that in many server environments it's not made easy to bundle up server-side data structures (object graphs) for easy delivery to the client. There may be information kept in server-side data structures that really shouldn't be delivered out to the client. Thus in order to send out a "pure" data-only response, the server would have to trim off sensitive data before delivering out the JSON.  That's not an unsolvable problem, but I don't know of many server frameworks that facilitate a solution.

The server has direct, unfettered access to the database and to everything else that makes an application work: user preferences, history, account details, system settings, etc. To build an application that's client-centric for rendering purposes would mean concocting ways of keeping all that information intact and up-to-date on the client. For a lot of applications, that might not be terribly easy.

Finally, it's only relatively recently that it would make sense to trust a browser to provide a stable enough platform for building a long-lived "application environment" as a continually-updating web page. By building a web app such that pages are sometimes completely reloaded, there are lots of little "reboots". That's a cheap and dumb way of keeping a lid on at least some kinds of memory leaks.

Comment: you make good points. Do you think a "pure data" server + intelligent client achieves better separation of concern (biz. logic data v/s presentation) or that its overall worse, as now the intelligence of the application is divided?

Comment: @na_ka_na well I don't know that I have enough experience to say. What I *do* know is that big applications tend to accumulate a *lot* of different "dimensions" of state information, and I think that handling that in a "pure data" sort of application is a fairly new challenge without much solid generally-accepted framework support. I do think it's an interesting idea and I hope to see a lot more work on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of sites with heavy Javascript use won't start executing until the DOM has fully loaded; then you'll get every page with 'loading screens' when the page wrapper has downloaded, but none of the content has.

Also, do remember that not all users have Javascript enabled, and not all browsers support high-level Javascript (think mobiles).

Answer (score 0):

I would send HTML in a response if I wanted my application to work without Javascript. I would write HTML rendering code in my server-side language (most of the time not Javascript), which could then be used for two purposes: serving whole HTML pages, and serving bits of HTML in response to XHRs.

If the Javascript code is restricted to things like reporting UI events and replacing `innerHTML` with server-generated code, I don't have to duplicate any of my application logic across languages/frameworks. This duplication problem is one of the reasons why server-side Javascript is getting people excited.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this old question and it is funny how history goes around in circles.

It is still an unsettled debate. There are even projects that go back to the hypertext roots and take it to the next level by sending HTML snippets over the wire. They keep the state and all the logic on the server, use almost no javascript on the client side, and still prevent full page reloads.